# unable to install the SASXport package

Tags: r

I read some online documentation to install the SASXport and it said to install the package from the below website https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/SASxport

I used the latest SASxport_1.7.0.tar.gz version of it and i could not install the package  SASxport. when i do so i get the below message which removes the SASxport package and when i call the library(SASxport) it says, there is no package called ‘SASxport’.

[image]

Could you please help me with this, like how to install this package?

Comment: Go up one line, see `'make' not found`. You don't have a suitable development environment. Do you have [Rtools](https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/) installed?

Comment: thank you @r2evans, i have tried to install the Rtools then again i get the message saying that package 'Rtools' is not available for this version of R

Comment: Did you look at the link I provided? Rtools is not a package for R, it is a set of tools for Windows, external to R, that are ***REQUIRED*** to be able to compile R packages with C/C++/Fortran code.

Comment: thank you @r2evans, understood what you are saying. I am now installing the same in my system.

Comment: @r2evans, i am now able to convert the data frame to xpt file, however the xpt file character variables values are not readable, numeric variables values are good, only issue is with character variables, could you please let me know the reason for this                       Note: Converted the xpt file to sas7bdat by proc copy

Comment: I have no idea what `xpt` is, nor how `SASxport` works. I don't use the package (nor SAS). If you've fixed this issue, we can close this question and I suggest you open a new question, focusing on making it as reproducible as you can. From there, I hope somebody with SAS experience can help resolve the issue here.